# Show woocommerce product description next to product name in orders deatils page at the backend and make it searchable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a help where i want to Show woocommerce product description next to product name in orders details page at the backend admin **ONLY** dashboard

So if product name is: **Mobile**
Product Description: **Type iPhone**

So i want the result to be: **Mobile Type iPhone**, instead of **Mobile**

[image]

I tried to achieve and searched the internet but couldn't reach a destination.

**I have achieved this by the code below:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_name', 'filter_order_item_get_name', 10, 2 );
function filter_order_item_get_name( $item_name, $order_item ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $order_item->is_type('line_item') ) {
        $product = $order_item->get_product();

        if( $description = $product->get_name() . " - " . $product->get_description() ) {
            $item_name = $description;
        }
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

**But still can't search by the product description as i want to search by the value of the product description itself not only the name to show the result of orders with this product description.**

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no hook to fix this and you can't easily overwrite admin templates. The intended way to do this is to use `woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers` from `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\meta-boxes\views\html-order-item.php` and add a column by echoing something like

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', function(){
    echo '<th class="sortable" data-sort="string-ins" style="max-width: 200px">Description</th>';
});
```

and use `woocommerce_admin_order_item_values` from `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\meta-boxes\views\html-order-item.php` to add the description in each row like

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', function($product){
    if( $product )
        echo '<td style="max-width: 200px">'.esc_html($product->get_description()).'</td>';
});
```

If you really want to add it to the title, you'll probably be better of using JavaScript.

**UPDATE**

If you want to search for products with similar short descriptions, you can use tags. This code adds the tags to the item rows. If you click them you'll go to the archive page.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', function($item_id, $item, $product){
    if( !$product )
        return;

    $tags = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_tag');
    if( $tags ){
        $html = '';
        foreach($tags as $tag)
            $html .= ($html ? ', ' : '').'<a href="/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&product_tag='.esc_attr($tag->slug).'">'.esc_html($tag->name).'</a>';
        echo ($html ? 'tags: '.$html : $html);
    }
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: can you check my updated answer ?, i have achieved it but still a small issue

Comment: @MagedMohamed: I've updated my answer. If you'd like to sort by description you do need a separate column to click on. Unless I'm missing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Want to search it with description not sort can this happen ?

Comment: @MagedMohamed: Why not show a list of product categories or tags?

Comment: I group in my mind each 3 products with a same description so need to search by description to list all the orders that include that 3 products

Comment: @MagedMohamed: Why don't you give those products also the same 3 tags, that's what they're for. Because searching by description you'll really need to dive into the core of WooCommerce and build custom queries.

Comment: You mean i can search by tags right ?, if yes i will try it

Comment: @MagedMohamed: yep

Comment: @MagedMohamed: I've updated my answer. Let me know if it helps.